# Unintentional flashing JS text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a text box that lists responses, adding a new line with each button click. This is eventually going to lead to an adventure game. My problem is this:

I cannot get the text to add on a line in the box, let alone stay. I have tried a variety of jquery and js operators but nothing seems to work. The text continues to flash once then disappear. Any suggestions?

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pocket Game</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css"-->
<script src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "returnbox">
    <p id = "box"></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <form>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>
        Possible Exits:
        </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <button class = "exit" id = "exit1" onclick="exit()">Exit1</button>
        <button class = "exit" id = "exit2" onclick="exit()">Exit2</button>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my js:

```
function exit()
{
    processCommand("Exit");
}

function processCommand(command)
{
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = command;
}
```

Comment: So all that is happening here is that you replace the contents of "box" with the string "Exit." If you are saying you want to add a new line each time you will want to do .innerHTML += command where command is itself a paragraph

Comment: Or make `box` a UL and add `LI` elements to it.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the text would disappear, though. It should stay until you call `processCommand` again, and be replaced with the new command.

Comment: Can u reproduce the issue on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing needed was 'type="button"' to be added to the attributes of the button, so:

```
<button type = "button" class = "exit" id = "exit2" onclick="exit()">Exit2</button>
```

Because the default type is form so it reloads the page upon click.